# Why ${path.module} points to the current directory ".", but not to the module directory?

Tags: terraform

I have used the following code:

```
module "instance" {
  for_each               = var.worker_private_ip
  source                 = "../../modules/ec2"
  env                    = var.env
  project_name           = var.project_name
  ami                    = var.ami
  instance_type          = var.instance_type
  subnet_id              = module.vpc.subnet_id
  vpc_security_group_ids = [module.security_group.security_group_id]
  private_ip             = each.value
  key_name               = var.public_key_name
  user_data              = file("${path.module}/startup.sh.tpl")
}
```

When I send terraform plan/apply command, I receive an error

```
path.module is "."

│ Invalid value for "path" parameter: no file exists at "./startup.sh.tpl";
```

So, terraform searching for file in current directory, but I expect for searching in (../../modules/ec2/)

I have startup.sh.tpl  file in module folder and if I set user_data to:

```
user_data              = file("../../modules/ec2/startup.sh.tpl")
```

everything is fine, also if I move sciprt to current directory everything ok too, plan and apply commands are correct

What am I doing wrong? Why `${path.module}` points to the current directory `"."`, but not to `../../modules/ec2/`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/references#filesystem-and-workspace-info):

> `path.module` is the filesystem path of the module where the expression is placed.

This means that it will return the relative path between your project's root folder and the location where `path.module` is used.

For example:

- if you are using it in a `.tf` file which is inside your `../../modules/ec2/` folder, it will return `../../modules/ec2`;
- if your are using it inside your `main.tf` (or any `.tf` file) in your project's root folder, it will return `.`

In your case, if the user data is inside the module, probably there would be need for it to make it as an input.

Comment: So if you omit `${path.module}/` then Terraform will always search relative to the project root directory instead of the subdirectory where the current `.tf` file is located?