# How to store terraform output values to s3 file

Tags: terraform

Is there any way to store terraform output values to s3 bucket file..

```
output "certificate_body" {
  description = "The acm certificate body"
  value       = venafi_certificate.this.certificate
}
```

how can we dump this output to a file which is in s3 bucket ?

Comment: What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an S3 object resource to your Terraform code:

```
resource "aws_s3_object" "object" {
  bucket  = "your_bucket_name"
  key     = "new_object_key"
  content = venafi_certificate.this.certificate
}
```

---

If you insist on using `terraform output` to create this S3 object, then that problem really exists outside of Terraform. You would have to do something like this:

```
terraform output certificate_body > /tmp/output.txt
aws s3 cp /tmp/output.txt s3://bucket/key
```

Comment: Small nit on the second part of the answer: `terraform output` produces human-readable output by default, but I'd guess that it would be better to use a machine-readable format if writing into S3 for something else to consume. That would mean using either `terraform output -json` or `terraform output -raw`, depending on the goal. But indeed, having Terraform directly manage an object in S3 is the more straightforward approach.

Answer (score 0):

Would be more appropiate to not use a terraform output resource. You can use terraform to write the content to a local file using a [local_file](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs/resources/file) resource and decide what to do with it. You can uploaded it with terraform to an s3 bucket using the [aws_s3_object](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_object) resource or upload it using the [aws s3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/upload-objects.html) cli.

To write the file:

```
resource "local_file" "foo" {
    content  = venafi_certificate.this.certificate
    filename = "${path.module}/venafi.certificate"
}
```

For clarification and using this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72481062/1154952) as reference: `path.module` is the filesystem path of the module where the expression is placed. Meaniong that it will return the relative path between your project's root folder and the location where path.module is used.